# magento getProductUrl does not include category path

Tags: magento

does getProductUrl return product url with the category path, how can i get it to work like that, it seems others will suggest to use a helper, but i guess it is not the only way.

Comment: By the way, i found an answer said if not in the category page, the getProductUrl will not include the category path, and i do put the product in the home page and try to get the url , so how to fix this ?

Comment: If you have a product collection, you will need to specify a category for each product in the collection. If you are using a category collection the category within the collection will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked it but I am quite sure the product needs to know about the category.

```
$product->setCategoryId($categoryId)->getProductUrl();
```

Answer (score 1):

The proposed answer did not work on my Magento version (1.9).

Here is what worked for me:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categorieId);
Mage::unregister('current_category');
Mage::register('current_category', $category);
$product->getProductUrl();
```